# Text Formatting toolbar continuously disappears in Impress (open office)

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice-impress, libreoffice-impress

This is a very weird and annoying problem. Not sure if it's a bug or a "feature"

I'm using OpenOffice 3.2 (within Ubuntu 10.04).

The Text Formatting toolbars disappear in many circumstances, e.g. each time I click out of a writing area. It's becoming very time consuming to go to View->Toolbars->TextFormatting to re-enable it each time.

3 questions:

1. is this expected behavior, and if so, is there any setting where I can change it? (note this wasn't happening in the past with other presentation I made)?
2. is there a workaround, such as defining a shortcut like CTRL-whatever that would make the toolbar appearing without menu joggling?
3. is anybody experiencing this too, especially someone using LibreOffice?

Comment: When it does appear, is it a separate window? If yes, try dragging it to the top, left, right, or bottom of the screen to "dock" it. See if it sticks there at all times.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in Windows LibreOffice too. And while you can make the toolbar re-appear using View/Toolbars/TextFormatting, it is often inoperable (greyed). It appears to be related to exactly what has been selected. As an example, selecting a text box, and then adding another to the selection vanishes the toolbar because in effect the text is no longer selected. However, if you right click the selection box and select 'character..' all the text may be formatted, even though this cannot be done with the toolbar...

Answer (score 1):

Mine got lost on Linux Mint. I spent time Googling.

I finally noticed that it has slipped up in the next tool bar, and by clicking on the vertical dots, I was able to drag it back in its own row below the other toolbar.